# how to scale a imageview in Android with a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview, android-button

I have this app im building that i want it to scale a imageview center.

This is my image

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/lamp" />
```

[image]

and two buttons + and -

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/plusBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/minusBtn"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cameraImageButton2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/minusBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_above="@+id/videoOnlineImageButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/videoOnlineImageButton" />
```

I want when you click on the minus the image to scale down. lets say it was 100x100 it could become 90x90
[image]

when you click on the plus to increase the size. lets say from 100x100 to 110x110

and so on.....

I need the image to scale and remain in the center of my screen. so somehow it should scale from its default size up or down.

---

***This is what worked for me guys thanks to Alpha mori!***

```
plusbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float x = imagview.getScaleX();
    float y = imagview.getScaleY();

    imagview.setScaleX((float) (x + 5));
    imagview.setScaleY((float) (y + 5));

            }
        });


  minusbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float x = imagview.getScaleX();
    float y = imagview.getScaleY();

    imagview.setScaleX((float) (x - 5));
    imagview.setScaleY((float) (y - 5));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plusbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float x = imagview.getScaleX();
    float y = imagview.getScaleY();

    imagview.setScaleX((float) (x + 5));
    imagview.setScaleY((float) (y + 5));

            }
        });


  minusbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float x = imagview.getScaleX();
    float y = imagview.getScaleY();

    imagview.setScaleX((float) (x - 5));
    imagview.setScaleY((float) (y - 5));

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think we also need to refresh the view once the image is scaled up/down

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you give me some further help how to add this on the button click?

Comment: Dear Alpha mori, I've implemented your code and see my update above to see how it came out. Maybe some modification is needed and it should be perfect!

Comment: Change "(float) (x - 0.5)" instead of "(float) (x - 5)".

Comment: Perfect Alpha mori! It worked... but Can i give it a min size so it doesn't disappear when i press minus?

Comment: You can put limit of x and y scale of Image.

Comment: will this work?                 if(x > 100) {
                    yourImageView.setScaleX((float) (x - 0.5));
                    yourImageView.setScaleY((float) (y - 0.5));
                }else{


                }